# Multithreading management in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, join, semaphore

What exactly does Perl do to threads that have completed its task? Does it let it idle or just kills it? I have a basic code structure below and I was wondering how to best optimize it.

```
use threads;
use Thread::Semaphore

my $s = Thread::Semaphore->new($maxThreads);
my @threads;
my $thread;

foreach my $tasktodo (@tasktodo) {
  $s->down();
  $thread = threads->new(\&doThis);
  push @threads, $thread;
}

foreach my $thr (@threads) {
  $thr->join();
}

sub doThis {
  # blah blah
  # completed, gonna let more threads run with $s->up()
  $s->up();
}
```

In this case, once a thread completes, I want to free up resources for more threads to run. I'm worried about joining threads at the end of the loop. If in the whole program life cycle it will have 4 threads created, will `@threads` still have 4 threads in it when joining?

Lets say `$maxThreads` is 2, will it run 2 threads then when those 2 completes, it will be killed and run 2 more threads. At the end it will only join or wait for those 2 threads running?

EDIT: I also don't care for the return values of these threads, that's why I want to free up resources. Only reason I'm joining is I want all threads to complete before continuing with the script. Again, is this the best implementation?

Comment: please call it `Perl`, not `PERL` or `perl` at least `Pearl`

Comment: Sorry, now I know. Are you able to answer my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual method for terminating a thread is to return EXPR from the entry point function with the appropriate return value(s).

The join function waits for this return value, and clean up the thread. So, in my opinion your code is fine.

Another way to exit a thread is this:

```
threads->exit(status);
```

Also, you can get a list of joinable threads with:

```
threads->list(threads::joinable);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was feeling uncertain about it. I know of the exit thread, but I didn't know if there was a need to at the end of the thread (since it's working now, I haven't stress tested it yet, will soon).